# Add track to playlist - post request to spotify API using fetch - not working

Tags: node.js, express, promise, fetch, spotify

I am trying to post a track uri and playlist Id to spotify API in order to add a track to a playlist.

I am using the url params and only one track at a time because spotify say you can do this 'The Spotify URIs of the tracks to add can be passed either in the query string or as a JSON array in the request body.' - spotify

The request hangs, nothing happens. No error, no response. In postman If I use the same bearer auth and url, I get the 'snapshot_id' as response, this is what I am looking for with the code.

I have tried an axios post and a fetch post, both behave the same.

```
async function updatePlaylist(accessToken, reqParams) {
    console.log('PARAMS _', reqParams);
    console.log('token _', accessToken);
    console.log('trying...');

    const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${reqParams.playlist_id}/tracks?uris=${reqParams.track_uri}`;

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('response promise is ', response.json())
        return response;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error('Update playlist call failed');
    });
}
```

```
async function updatePlaylist(accessToken, reqParams) {
    console.log('PARAMS _', reqParams);
    console.log('token _', accessToken);
    console.log('trying...');

    const url = 
  `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${reqParams.playlist_id}/tracks?uris=${reqParams.track_uri}`;

    return axios.post(url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('response promise is ', response)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('errrring ',err)
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
            return {statusCode: 401};
        }
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error('Get all play lists call failed');
    });
}
```

All my variables are there. I expect the 'snapshot_id' returned back to me confirming the update.

Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your content-length to 0 in the headers?

For example in the axios implementation it'd be like this

```
headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': '0'
        }
```

[Source](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/867)

Comment: I tried this now and it does fire a response at least, but a 401. This makes no sense as I can see the new access token being created and used, and a 401 returning with the new request. I also know my scopes are correct, it wasn't once and it mentions it in the response if it is a scope issue.

Comment: another thing I am not managing to do is kill the session so that spotify needs me to log in fresh, so I can see all the scopes and make sure I have the particular one registered. ERgh!

Comment: Actually I can see it in the network tab, its passing my scopes. That is all good.

Comment: I figured it out. Incase others see this. Use ***node-fetch*** to post to the spotify API. Then you will get that snapshot_id back. For some reason ***axios.post()*** does not go well with spotify.